# Understanding $\int W dW$ in stochastic integration

Tags: measure-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-differential-equations

Before going through stochastic differential equations we need to understand how stochastic integrals work and their meaning inside the equation (SDE). The book I'm following is developing a construction of this integral using an analogous version to Riemann Sums. My question is, given a stochastic process $\{W_t; t \in [0, + \infty)\}$ where $W_t:\Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and
$$
\int_0^TW dW
$$

how should I interpret $dW$? Is it the measure generated by the process? If so, how is described the measure generated by a process in general? Could I construct an analogous version of the Riemann sum but instead of considering the measure $dx$, considering $dW$ and integrate any other stochastic process with respect to this measure? How is interpreted the integral of a stochastic process in general? Does normal integration not apply in such cases, even if we fix $w\in \Omega$?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: No, the entire point is that Brownian motion does not have finite variation, and therefore does not induce a measure so that one needs to construct the stochastic integral.

Comment: And so what does de second term here mean?? I can't see the "riemann" rectangles here
$$
\sum^m_j W(\tau_{j-1})(W_{t_j} - W_{t_{j-1}})
$$
given $t_j$ a partition of $[0,T]$ and $\tau_{j-1}$ a "representative" point in the interval

Comment: What you wrote is not correct, if what you're intending on writing is an approximation for the stochastic integral.

Comment: If you are comfortable with measure theoretic probability, then there are many good sources covering the stochastic integral, I like  Le Gall's text. Karasztas and Shreve is more detailed. For non measure theoretic, not sure...maybe Shreve's texts on math finance?

Comment: Many thanks, I'm following "An introduction to stochastic differential equations" Lawrence C. Evans. Maybe I'm missing some details. I just wanted to "rethink" a new construction of the stochastic integral from the measure point of view but also with the Riemann Sums.

Comment: [Oksendal's book](https://www.amazon.ca/Stochastic-Differential-Equations-Introduction-Applications/dp/3540047581/ref=asc_df_3540047581/?tag=googleshopc0c-20&linkCode=df0&hvadid=312945754958&hvpos=&hvnetw=g&hvrand=12075748508180868003&hvpone=&hvptwo=&hvqmt=&hvdev=c&hvdvcmdl=&hvlocint=&hvlocphy=9000383&hvtargid=pla-455399119665&psc=1) is a good introductory text on this.